# Heroku: Could Not Find 'SOME GEM' in Cached Gems or Installed Localy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler

Attempting to push a rails project build to my heroku staging server from a branch.  Build log below.  Builds and runs fine in development in a docker container.  Currently have a previous build running on this same staging server.  Have tried bundle update, bundle install.  Have tried deleting the Gemlock.file too.  No luck.  Majorly stuck here.

```
  remote: -----> Build succeeded!
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected
    remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.3.25
    remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
    remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.2
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.3.25
    remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
    remote:        Fetching https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth.git
    remote:        Could not find dotenv-rails-2.8.1, rails-5.2.8.1, jquery-rails-4.5.1,
    remote:        bootsnap-1.15.0, aasm-5.4.0, geocoder-1.8.1, sidekiq-6.5.8,
    remote:        omniauth-google-oauth2-1.1.1, stripe-5.55.0, stripe_event-2.7.0,
    remote:        has_secure_token-1.0.0, friendly_id-5.4.2, dotenv-2.8.1, railties-5.2.8.1,
    remote:        racc-1.6.1, actioncable-5.2.8.1, actionmailer-5.2.8.1, actionpack-5.2.8.1,
    remote:        actionview-5.2.8.1, activejob-5.2.8.1, activemodel-5.2.8.1,
    remote:        activerecord-5.2.8.1, activestorage-5.2.8.1, activesupport-5.2.8.1, tilt-2.0.11,
    remote:        msgpack-1.6.0, bcrypt-3.1.18, rack-2.2.4, connection_pool-2.3.0, redis-4.8.0,
    remote:        faraday-2.7.1, omniauth-oauth2-1.8.0, jwt-2.5.0, oauth2-2.0.9,
    remote:        multipart-post-2.2.3, json-2.6.3, rack-proxy-0.7.4, i18n-1.12.0, mail-2.8.0,
    remote:        rack-test-2.0.2, rails-html-sanitizer-1.4.3, erubi-1.11.0, minitest-5.16.3,
    remote:        tzinfo-1.2.10, http-cookie-1.0.5, excon-0.94.0, faraday-net_http-3.0.2,
    remote:        snaky_hash-2.0.1, version_gem-1.1.1, rack-protection-3.0.4, net-imap-0.3.1,
    remote:        net-pop-0.1.2, net-smtp-0.3.3, loofah-2.19.0, rb-fsevent-0.11.2,
    remote:        net-protocol-0.2.0, timeout-0.3.1, unf_ext-0.0.8.2 in cached gems or installed
    remote:        locally
    remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth.git
    remote:        Could not find dotenv-rails-2.8.1, rails-5.2.8.1, jquery-rails-4.5.1,
    remote:        bootsnap-1.15.0, aasm-5.4.0, geocoder-1.8.1, sidekiq-6.5.8,
    remote:        omniauth-google-oauth2-1.1.1, stripe-5.55.0, stripe_event-2.7.0,
    remote:        has_secure_token-1.0.0, friendly_id-5.4.2, dotenv-2.8.1, railties-5.2.8.1,
    remote:        racc-1.6.1, actioncable-5.2.8.1, actionmailer-5.2.8.1, actionpack-5.2.8.1,
    remote:        actionview-5.2.8.1, activejob-5.2.8.1, activemodel-5.2.8.1,
    remote:        activerecord-5.2.8.1, activestorage-5.2.8.1, activesupport-5.2.8.1, tilt-2.0.11,
    remote:        msgpack-1.6.0, bcrypt-3.1.18, rack-2.2.4, connection_pool-2.3.0, redis-4.8.0,
    remote:        faraday-2.7.1, omniauth-oauth2-1.8.0, jwt-2.5.0, oauth2-2.0.9,
    remote:        multipart-post-2.2.3, json-2.6.3, rack-proxy-0.7.4, i18n-1.12.0, mail-2.8.0,
    remote:        rack-test-2.0.2, rails-html-sanitizer-1.4.3, erubi-1.11.0, minitest-5.16.3,
    remote:        tzinfo-1.2.10, http-cookie-1.0.5, excon-0.94.0, faraday-net_http-3.0.2,
    remote:        snaky_hash-2.0.1, version_gem-1.1.1, rack-protection-3.0.4, net-imap-0.3.1,
    remote:        net-pop-0.1.2, net-smtp-0.3.3, loofah-2.19.0, rb-fsevent-0.11.2,
    remote:        net-protocol-0.2.0, timeout-0.3.1, unf_ext-0.0.8.2 in cached gems or installed
    remote:        locally
    remote: 
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push failed
```

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.7.2'

gem 'dotenv-rails', require: 'dotenv/rails-now'

gem 'activeadmin', '~> 2.0'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.11.0.rc4'
gem 'mini_portile2'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'searchkick', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.2'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.4'
gem 'devise_token_auth', github: 'lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth', branch: 'master'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

gem 'rolify', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'
gem 'aasm', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.5'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'carrierwave-base64'
gem 'cloudinary', '~> 1.11', '>= 1.11.1'
gem 'fog-aws', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.1'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.5'
gem 'inline_svg'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.3.5'
gem 'pundit', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sidekiq', '<7'
gem 'streamio-ffmpeg', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.2'
gem "sentry-raven"

gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection"

gem 'stripe', '~> 5.11'
gem 'stripe_event', '~> 2.3'

gem 'has_secure_token'

gem 'gibbon', '~> 3.2'

gem 'ZCRMSDK', '~> 1.0.5'

gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.4.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
end

group :development do

  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'foreman', '~> 0.84.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'rb-readline'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
gem "webpacker", "~> 5.4"
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth.git
  revision: 17619afacaafc30783e8d78471260085df123626
  branch: master
  specs:
    devise_token_auth (1.2.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      devise (> 3.5.2, < 5)
      rails (>= 4.2.0, < 7.1)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    ZCRMSDK (1.0.5)
      json (~> 2.0)
      multipart-post (~> 2.0)
      rest-client (~> 2.0)
    aasm (5.4.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    actioncable (5.2.8.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.8.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.8.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.8.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.8.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.8.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.8.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.8.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.8.1)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.8.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.8.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activeadmin (2.9.0)
      arbre (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.1)
      formtastic (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      formtastic_i18n (~> 0.4)
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7)
      jquery-rails (~> 4.2)
      kaminari (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.1)
      railties (>= 5.2, < 6.2)
      ransack (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    activejob (5.2.8.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.8.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.8.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.8.1)
    activerecord (5.2.8.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.8.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.8.1)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.8.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.8.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.8.1)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
    activesupport (5.2.8.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.8.1)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    arbre (1.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 7.1)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.2, < 1.0)
    archive-zip (0.12.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    ast (2.4.2)
    aws_cf_signer (0.1.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.18)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.15.0)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.38.0)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    carrierwave (1.2.3)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    carrierwave-base64 (2.8.1)
      carrierwave (>= 0.8.0)
      mime-types (~> 3.0)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    chromedriver-helper (2.1.1)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    cloudinary (1.23.0)
      aws_cf_signer
      rest-client (>= 2.0.0)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
    connection_pool (2.3.0)
    crass (1.0.6)
    devise (4.8.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    domain_name (0.5.20190701)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    dotenv (2.8.1)
    dotenv-rails (2.8.1)
      dotenv (= 2.8.1)
      railties (>= 3.2)
    elasticsearch (7.4.0)
      elasticsearch-api (= 7.4.0)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 7.4.0)
    elasticsearch-api (7.4.0)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-transport (7.4.0)
      faraday
      multi_json
    erubi (1.11.0)
    excon (0.94.0)
    execjs (2.8.1)
    faraday (2.7.1)
      faraday-net_http (>= 2.0, < 3.1)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.4)
    faraday-net_http (3.0.2)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    fog-aws (1.4.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.38)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-core (1.45.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.58)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
    fog-json (1.2.0)
      fog-core
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-xml (0.1.4)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0)
    foreman (0.84.0)
      thor (~> 0.19.1)
    formatador (0.3.0)
    formtastic (4.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2.0)
    formtastic_i18n (0.7.0)
    friendly_id (5.4.2)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    geocoder (1.8.1)
    gibbon (3.4.4)
      faraday (>= 1.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.11.0)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    has_scope (0.8.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
    has_secure_token (1.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    hashie (5.0.0)
    http-accept (1.7.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.5)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (1.12.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    inherited_resources (1.13.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.2, < 7.1)
      has_scope (~> 0.6)
      railties (>= 5.2, < 7.1)
      responders (>= 2, < 4)
    inline_svg (1.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    io-like (0.3.1)
    ipaddress (0.8.3)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.5.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (2.6.3)
    jwt (2.5.0)
    kaminari (1.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-actionview (1.2.2)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.2.2)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-core (1.2.2)
    launchy (2.5.0)
      addressable (~> 2.7)
    letter_opener (1.8.1)
      launchy (>= 2.2, < 3)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.19.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.8.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    marcel (1.0.2)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (3.4.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2022.0105)
    mimemagic (0.3.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1)
      rake
    mini_magick (4.8.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.5.3)
    minitest (5.16.3)
    msgpack (1.6.0)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.2.3)
    net-imap (0.3.1)
      net-protocol
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.0)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.3)
      net-protocol
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.11.7)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.5.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    oauth2 (2.0.9)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 3.0)
      jwt (>= 1.0, < 3.0)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 4)
      snaky_hash (~> 2.0)
      version_gem (~> 1.1)
    omniauth (2.1.0)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6)
      rack (>= 2.2.3)
      rack-protection
    omniauth-facebook (9.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (1.1.1)
      jwt (>= 2.0)
      oauth2 (~> 2.0.6)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.8.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.8.0)
      oauth2 (>= 1.4, < 3)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)
    omniauth-rails_csrf_protection (1.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.2)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    parallel (1.22.1)
    parser (3.1.3.0)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
    pg (1.3.5)
    public_suffix (5.0.0)
    puma (3.12.6)
    pundit (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    racc (1.6.1)
    rack (2.2.4)
    rack-cors (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 2.0.0)
    rack-protection (3.0.4)
      rack
    rack-proxy (0.7.4)
      rack
    rack-test (2.0.2)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (5.2.8.1)
      actioncable (= 5.2.8.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.8.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.8.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.8.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.8.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.8.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.8.1)
      activestorage (= 5.2.8.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.8.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.8.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (5.2.8.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.8.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.8.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rainbow (3.1.1)
    rake (13.0.6)
    ransack (2.5.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (>= 5.2.4)
      i18n
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rb-readline (0.5.5)
    redis (4.8.0)
    regexp_parser (2.6.1)
    responders (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    rest-client (2.1.0)
      http-accept (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rolify (4.1.1)
    rubocop (1.39.0)
      json (~> 2.3)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 3.1.2.1)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.8, < 3.0)
      rexml (>= 3.2.5, < 4.0)
      rubocop-ast (>= 1.23.0, < 2.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.4.0, < 3.0)
    rubocop-ast (1.24.0)
      parser (>= 3.1.1.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.11.0)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.5)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    searchkick (4.6.3)
      activemodel (>= 5)
      elasticsearch (>= 6, < 7.14)
      hashie
    selenium-webdriver (4.7.1)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
    sentry-raven (3.1.2)
      faraday (>= 1.0)
    sidekiq (6.5.8)
      connection_pool (>= 2.2.5, < 3)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      redis (>= 4.5.0, < 5)
    snaky_hash (2.0.1)
      hashie
      version_gem (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    streamio-ffmpeg (3.0.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.8)
    stripe (5.55.0)
    stripe_event (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
      stripe (>= 2.8, < 9)
    thor (0.19.4)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.11)
    timeout (0.3.1)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.10)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.8.2)
    unicode-display_width (2.3.0)
    version_gem (1.1.1)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    webpacker (5.4.3)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket (1.2.9)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  ZCRMSDK (~> 1.0.5)
  aasm (~> 5.0, >= 5.0.5)
  activeadmin (~> 2.0)
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  carrierwave (~> 1.2.1)
  carrierwave-base64
  chromedriver-helper
  cloudinary (~> 1.11, >= 1.11.1)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  devise (~> 4.4)
  devise_token_auth!
  dotenv-rails
  fog-aws (~> 1.4, >= 1.4.1)
  foreman (~> 0.84.0)
  friendly_id (~> 5.4.0)
  geocoder (~> 1.5)
  gibbon (~> 3.2)
  has_secure_token
  inline_svg
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  letter_opener
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  mini_magick (~> 4.8.0)
  mini_portile2
  nokogiri (~> 1.11.0.rc4)
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-google-oauth2
  omniauth-rails_csrf_protection
  pg (~> 1.3.5)
  puma (~> 3.7)
  pundit (~> 2.0)
  rack-cors
  rails (~> 5.2, >= 5.2.1)
  rails_12factor
  rb-readline
  rolify (~> 4.1, >= 4.1.1)
  rubocop
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  searchkick (~> 4.4, >= 4.4.2)
  selenium-webdriver
  sentry-raven
  sidekiq (< 7)
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  streamio-ffmpeg (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.2)
  stripe (~> 5.11)
  stripe_event (~> 2.3)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webpacker (~> 5.4)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.7.2p137

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.26
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Deleted the "cache" subfolder in the "vendor" folder, which is in the rails project folder.